# Android Enable WebView Touch Sound

Tags: android-webview

I need to play touch sounds on Web view event clicks, I enabled the Touch sounds and tried it on android version less than 4.1 it works fine, from my Web View i click the radio button it make to hear the click sounds but on 4.1 and above it doesn't make click sound when I click radio button or button clicks even . I hope it's disabled from the sdk Web view itself at 4.1 and above. Let me have any possible solution to fix the issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not possible, since the events inside the WebView are not passed to the Android system, you  may have a chance to create such beheaviour by embedding these sounds inside the webpage you are rendering inside the WebView.